# Oracle SQL Query, How to get specific row details (filtering the rows) without using WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to know how to get a specific record (row) in the select query without using the "Where" clause. Generally, WHERE clause is used to filter the records to get specific row details. But, is there any other possibility to filter the rows without using a "WHERE" clause. I'm looking for a logical answer, and it means a great deal to me if you could help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Explaining the why and context for such an unusual request is a good idea here.

Comment: Hi, well I'm looking for possible solutions exploring more in depth in SQL programming. Seems like we can use "Having" clause as but looking for more answers. It is ok even if the statements impact performance, but just  to be clear in concepts. Thank you very much sstan.

Answer (score 0):

Teoretically you can use `group by` and `having` clause. But logical answer is use `SELECT ... WHERE  ...`

Answer (score 0):

To filter records, "**where**" & "**having**" are the only ones which do the job.

Another way is you can play around by using "**top**" & "**order by**" together, 
but i really doubt whether you can achieve your desired results of a "specific" row without where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING` clause **without** `GROUP BY`. Also you can use `inner join` with some (temporary) table.